# multiple physical USB conectors, single COM port?

Tags: windows, serial-port, arduino

I want to run a bunch of arduinos off a single computer, but I want all the arduinos to be in the same COM port. I don't mean having all of them plugged into a USB hub, I mean each different arduino reads and writes into the COM port, for example, four arduinos sending info to COM3 .

Comment: Likely not possible.

Comment: RS-232 is point-to-point. You would have to use a multi-point protocol such as RS-485 to connect one PC to many Arduino boards using a single *"serial"* connection.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible. Serial is single device per port, and is one of the oldest computer protocols still in place today.

Comment: much appreciated